# Is there a git remote service designed for non-code repos?

Tags: cloud-service, git, version-control

My girlfriend wants to use git to track progress on her artpieces, and doesn't want that to go into a public repo. Are there any remotes that explicitly support this, or should I just point her to BitBucket?

Comment: Manually migrated from [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1204025/360958)

Comment: I would suggest not to use Git because it's bad at handling binary files. PlasticSCM for example has better support for artistic files (it's one of their main features)

Comment: @AdriánArroyoCalle interesting! She uses SVGs, though, which is how I got the idea in the first place

Answer (score 1):

It's not always necessary that you store only source code in your git repositories; you can store anything, like PDFs, docs, images, etc.

As far as her artwork is concerned, I know it is important to keep them private. There are many other git providers out there offering free private repositories. Some of them are:

1. [Gitlab](http://gitlab.org/)
2. [Gitorious](https://gitorious.org/)
3. [ChiliProject](https://www.chiliproject.org/)
4. [Coding.net](https://coding.net/)
5. [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/)
6. [Codeplane](https://codeplane.com/)
7. Bitbucket

All of them provide free repositories. I would recommend (if not going for Bitbucket) Gitlab is also worth a try.